# Cannot evaluate org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse.toString()

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

When using the elasticsearch 6.4.1 with the RestHighLevelClient, I have got the error in the IndexResponseit is "Method threw 'java.lang.NoClassDefFounfError' exception. Cannot evaluate org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse.toString()"

Anyboday came across this problem? How do you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the elasticsearch 6.4.1 has a higher version dependency of jackson jars. I came across the same issue when I use the jackson version of 2.5.7 for all jars. After I have update jackson jars to be version 2.9.7, the error and some other error like:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.filter.TokenFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 41 more
```

are all gone.